# J4 API - There are two variables for Article Text, why do neither work on PATCH?

Tags: joomla-api, joomla-4.x, joomla-4, restful-api

While working with the new Joomla 4 web services API. The Article text does not update. Additionally, as per the documentation, when creating an article via API the article text variable is `articletext`, but the response provided shows the variable is now `text` and it is in data>attributes.

When attempting to edit/patch an article the Article Text update never takes. There is no error provided and a 200 response is given. But after examination, the article's text is not altered.

[Example video provided here.](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/6059450?key=e88fae288d9d9f8df3c79b02616593aa)

Why is this?

Comment: Are we looking here: https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/216247/SW7UcBAR#09fc98bc-8808-43c5-ae01-6e998c9edfb7 ? That reference doesn't indicate that PATCHing the articletext is an option (or maybe I'm wrong or the documentation is outdated / not exhaustive). This Joomla issue references PATCH and has some snippets that others have tested: https://issues.joomla.org/tracker/joomla-cms/35086  I also found that [PATCH 4.1.5 Update Article](https://www.postman.com/JoomlaLABS/workspace/luca-racchetti-s-public-workspace/request/9617873-dcafd460-f094-4783-9402-b4a26c2a8ecc) doesn't try articletext.

Comment: @Eoin served up some great content [here](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/31550/12352)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Patch is successful with caveats

instead of using `text` or `articletext` the correct variables are `introtext` and `fulltext`.

To note in one test both `introtext` & `fulltext` did not work together but worked successfully when patching them separately. i concluded that only happened when updating text that was entered into site editor manually and not designated intro or full text.

Subsequently, `introtext` and `fulltext` work successfully in all other cases.

Comment: When I asked for validation of this answer in RingCentral/Glip's Joomla! Community Public Channel, @ChristianeMaier-Stadtherr said: `articletext is the name of the input field for articles in a screen. At save, the model splits this articletext in two parts: introtext (the part before readmore) and fulltext (the part after readmore). In the frontend, these two parts are concatenated. So [this] answer is correct. But it is not related to J4` Then @Nicola Galgano said: `See #35086 on GitHub`